Enable option 66 and option 67 in kea dhcp
How can we enable option 66 and option 67 in  kea dhcp. We are using kea dhcp version: 2.1.1
on debian. We could not find much about it, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you in Advance :)

It is all in the docs.
See All DHCP options
Essentially, it is just:
"Dhcp4": {
  {
    "code": 66,
    "data": "tftp.example.org",
    "name": "tftp-server-name"
  },
  {
    "code": 67,
    "data": "boot-file.img",
    "name": "boot-file-name"
  },
}

